# firestore set/add functions not working and promise is never resolved

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Calling set on a doc or calling add function on a collection, never returns any response or error, and I can also not see any changes in the Firebase console. Although, read operations work fine and I can get data using get() on a collection.

```js
const db = firebase.firestore();
  const data = {
    name: 'Product2',
    sku: 'sku',
  };
  console.log('here before');
  db.collection('stores').doc('store1')
    .collection('products').doc('YOigFkuBVFk70SSlXz9g')
    .set(data)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      dispatch(slice.actions.setProducts([]));
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      dispatch(slice.actions.setProducts([]));
      console.log(e);
    });
```

Here are the rules from the Firebase console:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you make sure that code is reachable by adding a log statement before that `set()`? Also is there any activity in network logs ?

Comment: Which version are you using? I saw a similar issue a few hours ago but that was while read data. There should have been some logs in network tab if requests were made.

Comment: I am using firebase version 8.2.3. But there are no logs in the Network tab.

Comment: are you able to see any error in logs?

Comment: It was a version issue, thank you @DivyaniYadav.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded to version 9, and the issue is fixed.